# Как сохранить ModelState при RedirectToAction в ASP.NET MVC 6?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

У меня есть метод для удаления объекта. Удаление не имеет собственного представления, а представляет из себя кнопку "Удалить" в "EditReport". При успешном удалении происходит перенаправление на "Report".

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("{reportId:int}")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult DeleteReport(int reportId)
    {
        var success = _reportService.DeleteReportControl(reportId);
        if (success == false)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Error", "Произошла ошибка при удалении шаблона. Пожалуйста попробуйте еще раз удалить шаблон");
            return RedirectToAction("EditReport");
        }
        ModelState.AddModelError("OK", "Шаблон успешно удален");
        return RedirectToAction("Report");
    }
```

В ASP.NET MVC 5 использовал следующие атрибуты для сохранения ModelState между методами. Взято отсюда: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12024227/3878213

```
public class SetTempDataModelStateAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);         
        filterContext.Controller.TempData["ModelState"] = 
           filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState;
    }
}

public class RestoreModelStateFromTempDataAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        if (filterContext.Controller.TempData.ContainsKey("ModelState"))
        {
            filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState.Merge(
                (ModelStateDictionary)filterContext.Controller.TempData["ModelState"]);
        }
    }
}
```

Но в ASP.NET MVC 6 RC 1(ASP.NET Core 1.0) данный код не работает. Ошибка в
filterContext.Controller не содержит определения для TempData и ViewData.

Хотел оставить комментарий в исходном ответе, но для этого у меня не хватает очков для комментирования.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается что ASP.NET ядро не поддерживает сериализацию состояния модели (из-за ModelStateEntry, содержащую исключения).

Таким образом, нельзя сериализовать состояние модели в TempData. И, как написано в этом [вопросе GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4190), по-видимому не будет никаких планов изменить это поведение.

Поэтому пришлось написать собственное решение:

```
public class SetTempDataModelStateAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);

        Controller controller = filterContext.Controller as Controller;
        if (controller != null)
        {
            controller.TempData["ModelState"] = controller.ViewData.ModelState;
        }
    }
}

public class RestoreModelStateFromTempDataAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

        Controller controller = filterContext.Controller as Controller;
        if (controller != null & controller.TempData.ContainsKey("ModelState"))
        {
            controller.ViewData.ModelState.Merge(
                (ModelStateDictionary)controller.TempData["ModelState"]);
        }
    }
}
```